# Identify what foreign keys have 1 to many values and 1-1 relationships to certain column's values within the table

Tags: sql, database

I am joining `table_2` & `table_3` below, as you can see in some records the surrogate key `Father` in `table_3` contains many values of `Hats`, to 1 value of `Father`.

I need to identify the values of `Father` in `Table_3` have many `Hat` values to 1 `Father` as it should be 1 to 1 to hats to Father. How can I write a query (I can have two different that is ok :)) that shows the ID's that have a 1-1 relationship and then the id's that have a 1-many.

I am having trouble writing a query that outputs **WHAT** `TABLE_3` `Fathers` have 1-to-many relationships with `Hats` and what `table_3` `Father` values have 1-to-1 relationships with `Hats`. It makes it trickier because a `Father` can have many Kids.

Use SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com to follow along on the code here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_2` 
(
    `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `Father` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `kids_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `table_2` (`id`, `Father`, `kids_name`) 
VALUES ('1', 'John', 'Charlie'),
       ('2', 'John', 'Jamie'),
       ('3', 'John', 'Stevie'),
       ('4', 'Joe', 'Stacy'),
       ('5', 'Joe', 'Arnold'),
       ('6', 'Jeremy', 'Lacy'),
       ('7', 'Jack', 'Lacy');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_3` 
(
    `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `Father` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `Hat_Type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `table_3` (`id`,`Father`, `Hat_Type`) 
VALUES ('1', 'John', 'Fidora'),
       ('2', 'John','Bowl'),
       ('3', 'Joe', 'berka'),
       ('4', 'Jeremy', 'Beanie'),
       ('5', 'Jack', 'Cap'),
       ('6', 'NULL', 'Hood');
```

Select statement here:

```
select 
    a.Father, a.kids_name, b.hat_type
from
    table_2 a
join 
    table_3 b on a.Father = b.Father
```

This is the returned result set:

```
Father  kids_name   hat_type
-----------------------------
John    Charlie Fidora
John    Charlie Bowl
John    Jamie   Fidora
John    Jamie   Bowl
John    Stevie  Fidora
John    Stevie  Bowl
Joe Stacy   berka
Joe Arnold  berka
Jack    Lacy    Cap
```

I need to parse out all the values where a the same Father has two hats, so I can send to my DB team and let them know he , look into these records and deactivate a hat_type for Father in table_3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data model might be up for some [normalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

For example:

**Sample data:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl1_dads
> (
>   Father_Id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   Father_Name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (Father_Id)
> );
>
> ALTER TABLE tbl1_dads 
>  AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
>
> INSERT INTO tbl1_dads
> (Father_Name) 
> VALUES ('Unknown');
>
> INSERT INTO tbl1_dads
> (Father_Name) VALUES
> ('John'),
> ('Joe'),
> ('Jeremy'),
> ('Jack');
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl2_daddy_spawns 
> (
>  Spawn_Id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>  Father_Id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>  Kid_Name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
>  PRIMARY KEY (Spawn_Id),
>  KEY (Father_Id, Kid_Name),
>  FOREIGN KEY (Father_ID) 
>    REFERENCES tbl1_dads(Father_Id)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO `tbl2_daddy_spawns` 
> (Father_Id, Kid_Name) VALUES 
>  (101, 'Charlie'),
>  (101, 'Jamie'),
>  (101, 'Stevie'),
>  (102, 'Stacy'),
>  (102, 'Arnold'),
>  (103, 'Lacy'),
>  (104, 'Lacy');
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl3_daddy_hats
> (
>  Id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>  Father_Id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>  Hat_Type VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
>  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
>  KEY (Father_Id, Hat_Type),
>  FOREIGN KEY (Father_ID) 
>    REFERENCES tbl1_dads(Father_Id)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tbl3_daddy_hats
> (Father_Id, Hat_Type) VALUES 
> (101, 'Fidora'),
> (101, 'Bowl'),
> (102, 'Berka'),
> (103, 'Beanie'),
> (104, 'Cap'),
> (100, 'Hood');
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> select dad.father_id, dad.father_name
> , count(distinct kid.spawn_id) as kids
> , count(distinct hat.id) as hats
> from tbl1_dads as dad
> left join tbl2_daddy_spawns as kid
>   on kid.father_id = dad.father_id
> left join tbl3_daddy_hats as hat
>   on hat.father_id = dad.father_id
> group by dad.father_id, dad.father_name
> having hats > 1
> ```

**Result:**

> ```
> father_id | father_name | kids | hats
> --------: | :---------- | ---: | ---:
>       101 | John        |    3 |    2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f465bf1e10e94a676fd9e6616ca278a)*

Answer (score 0):

This answers the question as originally formulated.
You can use window functions:

```
select ab.*
from (select a.id, b.father, a.kids_name, b.Hat_Type,
             count(*) over (partition by a.id) as cnt
      from table_2 a join
           table_3 b
           on a.father = b.father
     ) ab
where cnt >= 2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6040a8eaca64c45d7efbeb93e55f843f) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

For your revised question, I think you just want aggregation with `count(distinct)`:

```
select b.father, count(distinct b.hat_type)
from table_3 b
group by b.father;
```

You should then fix your data model.  You should have a table that has one row per "father" with a single column for "hat_type".

Comment: I get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by a.id) as cnt from table_1 a join table_2 b ' at line 7  @Gordon Linoff. Thank you for response

Comment: I updated the query, as I actually have a more complex problem than I initially input, I am sorry.